# Manage Kubernetes cluster from UI

Tags: docker, containers, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes

Is there any known approach with which we can manage the Kubernetes cluster from a dashboard kind of UI? Kubernetes by default comes up with a UI which is good enough to view the details of running pods, services etc.

But what is the approach if we need to modify some properties of Kubernetes cluster (*like increasing the replicas on RC, change auto-scaling policies etc.*) from UI rather than issuing kubectl commands?

I had heard that [Kismatic](http://thenewstack.io/kismatic-hopes-foster-ecosystem-contributing-webui-code-kubernetes-project/) is working towards achieving this same goal, but i am not quite sure how to configure from their [github](https://github.com/kismatic) projects.

I am using Google cloud for my projects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The UI that runs by default in Kubernetes doesn't currently support modifying anything running in the cluster, and there aren't any other official UIs that do. It's something that we'd definitely like to improve in the future.

However, the fabric8 folks have put together a console that does allow you to change what's running in a Kubernetes cluster in addition to viewing it. I haven't tried it myself so I can't vouch for it, but it may be worth checking out. There's a video demo [here](https://vimeo.com/134408470), with documentation [here](http://fabric8.io/guide/console.html).

Comment: Tried out fabric8. Works like a charm.